# Animated series with jump-through portals

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember an animated series or possibly an anime where the protagonist jumps (in a spaceship) through portals using a big ramp.

There was a villain trio with stupid girl with annoying laugh.

Does somebody know it or am I crazy?

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: [Time Bokan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Du6ZxpfP4Os)?

Comment: No, Time Bokan is not right...

Comment: Be aware that Time Bokan is the name of a specific crossover OAV but it is also used to reference a whole set of anime series by the same authors who shares common plot devices and characters archetypes.

Comment: Definetely not Time Bokan - there were three villains - male chief and two girl sidekick..

Comment: It has something to do with traveling in another realm and the ramp was hide in big mechanic mansion, which will open when they need the ramp... (sorry my english is rusty...)

Comment: As Valorum has said it would be a lot easier for people to identify this for you if you could [edit] in anymore details you remember. Where you saw it, when you saw it, when you think it was made, any specific plot points, animation style, etc.

Comment: So, do you remember any more of the mechanics of this? Did the spaceship drive up the ramp before going off the end into the portal? Was it propelling itself in another manner? Launched? Was the portal at the very end of the ramp, or did the ship travel a but through the air before entering?

Answer (score -2):

This may be **[Wakfu: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakfu_(TV_series))**

Comment: Hi there. Could you please [edit] in the elements that make you think this is the one? For instance, if we're thinking about the same girl, there's indeed a very stupid one in Wakfu - maybe you could tell us if that's something you remembered? Or a picture or video of said portals?

Comment: No, unfortunately no...